# Getting the value of an item in the array

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following items stored in an array-string in String.xml file

```
    <string-array name="cr">
    <item name="x"> 20</item>
    <item name="y"> 40</item>
    <item name="z"> 60</item>
    <item name="k"> 80</item>
    <item name="i"> 100</item>
    <item name="l"> 120</item>

</string-array>
```

how can i get the value (eg 80) using the item  name in mainactivity.java file?

int index =Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cr)).indexOf(..); I tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use two array(one for key, one for value) and then put them into Hashmap object.**

Example:

```
    String[] mobileArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mobile);
    String[] priceArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.price);

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mobileArray.length; i++) {
        map.put(mobileArray[i], priceArray[i]);
    }
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="mobile">
        <item>Samsung</item>
        <item>Lenevo</item>
        <item>Karbon</item>
        <item>Moto</item>
        <item>Xperia</item>
        <item>Micromax</item>
        <item>Lava</item>
        <item>Xiomi</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="price">
        <item>10000</item>
        <item>12000</item>
        <item>10000</item>
        <item>12000</item>
        <item>10000</item>
        <item>12000</item>
        <item>10000</item>
        <item>12000</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: @NAZXD: mark it as an answer, so it can be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this

```
String[] yourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array. cr);
String yourString = yourArray[3];
```

hope this is what you need

Comment: Thanks for your help but String yourString = yourArray[i]; I need to look by using a variable not a number

Comment: It is an array, not a map and you can only get the value of the items with their index, you can't access the item names. You could have a second array with the names and build a map at runtime if you really need to access your values by their name.

Comment: How can I create the map ? since I alreagy have another array of the item names